# Error while executing hive Query : org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.io.HiveDecimalWritable cannot be cast to org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

I am running query on hive ....seems from logs , it is failing because of erroneous record in table [date_dim] causing casting exception ....when I looked for other records in [date_dim], nothing different in particular record(see sample records at last).

I may be wrong pointing to particular record...trying to understand why this casting error and how this can be resolved ?

Can you please help me understand why error for this particular record ? how it can be resolved ?
Any help is highly appreciated !!!

**Hive query :**

```
SELECT 'store' AS channel, 'ss_cdemo_sk' AS col_name, d_year, d_qoy,  i_category, ss_ext_sales_price AS ext_sales_price 
FROM  store_sales     ,  item     ,  date_dim    
WHERE ss_cdemo_sk IS NULL  
AND ss_sold_date_sk = d_date_sk  
AND ss_item_sk = i_item_sk ;
```

**Hive logs :**

```
Query ID = root_20150922151717_a94d4679-224b-41f3-8336-a799d4ebedab
Total jobs = 4
....


Launching Job 3 out of 4
Number of reduce tasks is set to 0 since there's no reduce operator
Starting Job = job_1441794795162_13426, Tracking URL = http://myhost:8035/proxy/application_1441794795162_13426/
Kill Command = /opt/hes/hadoop/hadoop-2.6.0//bin/hadoop job  -kill job_1441794795162_13426
Hadoop job information for Stage-6: number of mappers: 1; number of    reducers: 0
2015-09-22 15:18:34,291 Stage-6 map = 0%,  reduce = 0%
2015-09-22 15:18:54,541 Stage-6 map = 100%,  reduce = 0%
Ended Job = job_1441794795162_13426 with errors
Error during job, obtaining debugging information...
Examining task ID: task_1441794795162_13426_m_000000 (and more) from job job_1441794795162_13426

Task with the most failures(4):
Task ID:task_1441794795162_13426_m_000000
URL : myhost:8088/taskdetails.jsp?jobid=job_1441794795162_13426&tipid=task_1441794795162_13426_m_000000
-----
Diagnostic Messages for this Task:
Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: Hive Runtime Error while processing row **{"d_date_sk":2452538,"d_date_id":"AAAAAAAAKDMGFCAA","d_date":"2002-09-20","d_month_seq":1232,"d_week_seq":5360,"d_quarter_seq":412,"d_year":2002,"d_dow":5,"d_moy":9,"d_dom":20,"d_qoy":3,"d_fy_year":2002,"d_fy_quarter_seq":412,"d_fy_week_seq":5360,"d_day_name":"Friday   ","d_quarter_name":"N","d_holiday":"2002Q3","d_weekend":"N","d_following_holiday":"Y","d_first_dom":2452761,"d_last_dom":2452519,"d_same_day_ly":2452447,"d_same_day_lq":2452173,"d_current_day":"N","d_current_week":"N","d_current_month":"N","d_current_quarter":"N","d_current_year":"N"}**
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.ExecMapper.map(ExecMapper.java:185)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:54)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:450)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:343)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:163)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1628)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:158)
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: Hive Runtime Error while processing row {"d_date_sk":2452538,"d_date_id":"AAAAAAAAKDMGFCAA","d_date":"2002-09-20","d_month_seq":1232,"d_week_seq":5360,"d_quarter_seq":412,"d_year":2002,"d_dow":5,"d_moy":9,"d_dom":20,"d_qoy":3,"d_fy_year":2002,"d_fy_quarter_seq":412,"d_fy_week_seq":5360,"d_day_name":"Friday   ","d_quarter_name":"N","d_holiday":"2002Q3","d_weekend":"N","d_following_holiday":"Y","d_first_dom":2452761,"d_last_dom":2452519,"d_same_day_ly":2452447,"d_same_day_lq":2452173,"d_current_day":"N","d_current_week":"N","d_current_month":"N","d_current_quarter":"N","d_current_year":"N"}
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapOperator.process(MapOperator.java:503)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.ExecMapper.map(ExecMapper.java:176)
... 8 more
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: Unexpected exception: org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.io.HiveDecimalWritable cannot be cast to org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapJoinOperator.processOp(MapJoinOperator.java:311)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.forward(Operator.java:815)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.FilterOperator.processOp(FilterOperator.java:120)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.forward(Operator.java:815)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.TableScanOperator.processOp(TableScanOperator.java:95)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapOperator$MapOpCtx.forward(MapOperator.java:157)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapOperator.process(MapOperator.java:493)
... 9 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.io.HiveDecimalWritable cannot be cast to org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.objectinspector.primitive.WritableIntObjectInspector.get(WritableIntObjectInspector.java:36)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.udf.generic.GenericUDFOPEqual.evaluate(GenericUDFOPEqual.java:84)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.ExprNodeGenericFuncEvaluator._evaluate(ExprNodeGenericFuncEvaluator.java:185)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.ExprNodeEvaluator.evaluate(ExprNodeEvaluator.java:77)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.ExprNodeGenericFuncEvaluator$DeferredExprObject.get(ExprNodeGenericFuncEvaluator.java:86)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.udf.generic.GenericUDFOPAnd.evaluate(GenericUDFOPAnd.java:68)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.ExprNodeGenericFuncEvaluator._evaluate(ExprNodeGenericFuncEvaluator.java:185)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.ExprNodeEvaluator.evaluate(ExprNodeEvaluator.java:77)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.ExprNodeEvaluator.evaluate(ExprNodeEvaluator.java:65)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.FilterOperator.processOp(FilterOperator.java:106)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.forward(Operator.java:815)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.CommonJoinOperator.internalForward(CommonJoinOperator.java:638)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.CommonJoinOperator.genUniqueJoinObject(CommonJoinOperator.java:651)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.CommonJoinOperator.genUniqueJoinObject(CommonJoinOperator.java:654)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.CommonJoinOperator.checkAndGenObject(CommonJoinOperator.java:750)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapJoinOperator.processOp(MapJoinOperator.java:299)
... 15 more


FAILED: Execution Error, return code 2 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.MapRedTask
ATTEMPT: Execute BackupTask: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.MapRedTask
.......
Stage-Stage-8: Map: 2   Cumulative CPU: 42.59 sec   HDFS Read: 122983367 HDFS Write: 5267230 SUCCESS
Stage-Stage-6: Map: 1   HDFS Read: 0 HDFS Write: 0 FAIL
Stage-Stage-2: Map: 2  Reduce: 1   Cumulative CPU: 8.78 sec   HDFS Read: 15648221 HDFS Write: 8106 SUCCESS
Total MapReduce CPU Time Spent: 51 seconds 370 msec
OK
channel    col_name    d_year    d_qoy    i_category    ext_sales_price
store    ss_cdemo_sk    1998    1    Sports                                                NULL
.....
.
.
.
..
```

**Sample data of table from date_dim ( including erroneous record )**

hive > select * from date_dim ;

```
date_dim.d_date_sk    date_dim.d_date_id    date_dim.d_date    date_dim.d_month_seq    date_dim.d_week_seq    date_dim.d_quarter_seq    date_dim.d_year    date_dim.d_dow    date_dim.d_moy    date_dim.d_dom    date_dim.d_qoy   date_dim.d_fy_year    date_dim.d_fy_quarter_seq    date_dim.d_fy_week_seq    date_dim.d_day_name    date_dim.d_quarter_name    date_dim.d_holiday    date_dim.d_weekend    date_dim.d_following_holiday    date_dim.d_first_dom    date_dim.d_last_dom    date_dim.d_same_day_ly    date_dim.d_same_day_lq    date_dim.d_current_day    date_dim.d_current_week    date_dim.d_current_month    date_dim.d_current_quarter    date_dim.d_current_year

2452538    AAAAAAAAKDMGFCAA    2002-09-20    1232    5360    412    2002    5    9    20    3    2002    412    5360    Friday       N    2002Q3    N    Y    2452761    2452519    2452447    2452173    N    N    N    NN

2431208    AAAAAAAAIOIBFCAA          1944-04-27    531      2313    178    1944    4     4    27    2    1944    178    2313    Thursday     N    1944Q2    N    N    2431272    2431182    2431117    2430842    N    N    N    NN

2456494    AAAAAAAAOKLHFCAA       2013-07-20    1362    5925    455    2013     6    7    20    3    2013    455    5925    Saturday     N    2013Q3    N    Y    2456655    2456475    2456403    2456129    N    N    N    NN

2481780    AAAAAAAAEHONFCAA       2082-10-12    2193    9537    732    2082    1    10    12    4    2082    732   9537    Monday       N    2082Q4    N    N    2482041    2481769    2481688    2481415    N    N    N    NN
```

**hive> describe store_sales ;**

```
ss_sold_date_sk         int                                         
ss_sold_time_sk         int                                         
ss_item_sk              int                                         
ss_customer_sk          int                                         
ss_cdemo_sk             int                                         
ss_hdemo_sk             int                                         
ss_addr_sk              int                                         
ss_store_sk             int                                         
ss_promo_sk             int                                         
ss_ticket_number        int                                         
ss_quantity             int                                         
ss_wholesale_cost       decimal(7,2)                                
ss_list_price           decimal(7,2)                                
ss_sales_price          decimal(7,2)                                
ss_ext_discount_amt     decimal(7,2)                                
ss_ext_sales_price      decimal(7,2)                                
ss_ext_wholesale_cost   decimal(7,2)                                
ss_ext_list_price       decimal(7,2)                                
ss_ext_tax              decimal(7,2)                                
ss_coupon_amt           decimal(7,2)                                
ss_net_paid             decimal(7,2)                                
ss_net_paid_inc_tax     decimal(7,2)                                
ss_net_profit           decimal(7,2)
```

**hive> describe item ;**

```
i_item_sk               int                                         
i_item_id               string                                      
i_rec_start_date        date                                        
i_rec_end_date          date                                        
i_item_desc             string                                      
i_current_price         decimal(7,2)                                
i_wholesale_cost        decimal(7,2)                                
i_brand_id              int                                         
i_brand                 string                                      
i_class_id              int                                         
i_class                 string                                      
i_category_id           int                                         
i_category              string                                      
i_manufact_id           int                                         
i_manufact              string                                      
i_size                  string                                      
i_formulation           string                                      
i_color                 string                                      
i_units                 string                                      
i_container             string                                      
i_manager_id            int                                         
i_product_name          string
```

**hive> describe date_dim ;**

```
d_date_sk               int                                         
d_date_id               string                                      
d_date                  date                                        
d_month_seq             int                                         
d_week_seq              int                                         
d_quarter_seq           int                                         
d_year                  int                                         
d_dow                   int                                         
d_moy                   int                                         
d_dom                   int                                         
d_qoy                   int                                         
d_fy_year               int                                         
d_fy_quarter_seq        int                                         
d_fy_week_seq           int                                         
d_day_name              string                                      
d_quarter_name          string                                      
d_holiday               string                                      
d_weekend               string                                      
d_following_holiday     string                                      
d_first_dom             int                                         
d_last_dom              int                                         
d_same_day_ly           int                                         
d_same_day_lq           int                                         
d_current_day           string                                      
d_current_week          string                                      
d_current_month         string                                      
d_current_quarter       string                                      
d_current_year          string
```

Comment: Can you give the full schema of the date_dim table

Comment: @mattinbits : updated question for table schema ...let me know if need other details

Comment: Is the table over JSON data? Are you sure its an erroneous row and not just that this is the first row, and the data is generally incompatible with your table definition?

Comment: Nope....table is not over JSON data... Sorry .it was my occurrence that error is coming for that row only... but surely this is first row caused error

Comment: @mattinbits : on "the data is generally incompatible with your table definition?"   can you help me understand and verify this.

Comment: @mattinbits : data incompatibility with table definition could not be issue  as I have created table first and then inserted records through INSERT AS  SELECT in all tables ....